# React pass the props of a component as a function variable

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a clicker game and I am not that far into it, but there is something that I don't understand about React.

I have made a tap button that works, and I was trying to make an upgrade button, but the problem is that it increases the power of the click, but it doesn't take any gold away from the player.

How can I make it so that it subtracts the cost on click?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tyfwft

Comment: You are not giving a `price` prop to your `App` component, so `cost` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

So you're kinda close, you just can't use props like that. `this.props` will always be a reference to the component's props you're in - not the props from where the function was called.

What you wanna do is update your handleGold/handleUpgrades functions to take an argument which will be the price props you pass down like:

`<Upgrade price = {5} handleGold = {(price) => this.handleUpgrades(price)}/>`

&

```
handleUpgrades(price) {
    let newGold = this.state.gold - price;
    let newPower = this.state.power++;
    if ( this.state.gold >= price) {
      this.setState({
        gold : newGold,
        power : newPower,
      });
    }
  }
```

and finally, in your Upgrade component, simply pass the price from props into that function:

`<button onClick = {() => this.props.handleGold(this.props.price)}>`